# How do I assign values to strings in a table?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write some code for my parents' business that will help them quote easily without the use of paper using `raw_input` and `%s`.
The customer explains the dimensions of the room and the carpet type they want, and presto they get a quoted price, this is not including labor, discounts and gst just yet.

What I'm trying to do however is assign prices to the carpets that I've put in a table, I just don't know how i.e `CarpetPrice = ["Green", "Blue", "Yellow"]`
How do I assign numbers (prices) to those.

Any help or suggestions on the table dilemma or on how I can improve this code would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

So let's make the following assumptions:

1. You ask the customer for the length and width of the room/area they want to carpet (say they input in meters)
2. You ask the customer what color carpet they want to use
3. Each carpet color has an associated price per square meter
4. You can sell fractional square meters of carpet (you are able to sell 10.5 square meters of carpet, without forcing the customer to buy 11 square meters of carpet)

This code should do your work for you:

```
while True:
    try: width = float(raw_input("Please enter the width of the room: "))
    except: continue
    else: break

while True:
    try: length = float(raw_input("Please enter the length of the room: "))
    except: continue
    else: break

color = None
validColors = set('green yellow blue'.split())
while color not in validColors:
    color = raw_input("Please enter the desired carpet color: ").lower()

unitPrices = {'green':10, 'yellow': 20.5, 'red':15}
print "The carpet price for a %(color)s carpet to fill an area of %(width)s m x %(length)s m = %(area)s sq. m. is $ %(cost)s" %{'color':color, 'width':width, 'length':length, 'area':width*length, 'cost':unitPrices[color]*width*length}
```

Comment: Could just move up `unitPrices` (perhaps re-naming it) and remove the `set` stuff? :p

Answer (score 0):

Another solution beside the dict is work with tuples:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

zipped = zip(a, b)
```

Output from zipped:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
```

Comment: If you want to look them up, I'm with you. But he ask's: "`CarpetPrice = ["Green", "Blue", "Yellow"]` How do I assign numbers (prices) to those?" - and with tuples this is one possibility. Maybe he could use tuples in another case.. :)